# How to trigger update of ExternalProject when UPDATE_DISCONNECTED set to ON

Tags: cmake

I have following CMakeLists.txt file in *external* directory in my project root. It is supposed fetch *Catch* (header only unit test library) for me.

```
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(
   Catch
   # I want to have it downloaded only once, 
   # therefore CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR which is projectRoot/external
   PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Catch
   GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/philsquared/Catch.git
   # disables auto update on every build
   UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1
   # disable following, since it is not needed
   CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
   BUILD_COMMAND ""
   INSTALL_DIR ""
   INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

It works well for me, except one thing.

I have set UPDATE_DISCONNECTED to 1 since I do not want to check for updates in every build I make (checking for updates takes some time).

But I would still like to have the opportunity to update external project from CMake itself. Eg. by doing `make Catch_update` or `make external_update_all` or whatever.

Is there better way to do that than writing custom target calling `git pull` in external project directory? If yes, then how? Thanks!

Comment: It should download the newest version when you remove the folder it downloads to. Not sure if `make clean` actually removes this though.

Comment: yes, but then new `git clone` is more time consuming than `git pull`. In this case Catch repo is small, so clone takes only seconds, but still... There must be a better way. :) At least I hope there is... In worst case, I will use custom target with `git pull` in external project directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, so after additional searching, this seems to be the only way to do this. Add custom target with an update. It is not pretty, but it is working.

```
#we need git executable
find_package(Git REQUIRED)

# update Catch target
add_custom_target(external-Catch-update
    COMMENT "Updated Catch"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Catch/src/Catch
    COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} pull
    DEPENDS Catch)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ExternalProject module has a Target Option, `STEP_TARGETS`, to which you can add, for instance, "update". In your call to `ExternalProject_Add`, simply add a line, `STEP_TARGETS update`. That will automatically create a target (in your case, Catch-update), which calls a pretty sophisticated CMake script (in your case, probably projectRoot/external/Catch/tmp/Catch-gitupdate.cmake). The ExternalProject module itself creates this gitupdate script. The script does a lot more than a simple pull; it will stash local changes, as needed, and pop them back, for instance. I just used this about a week ago and was pretty happy with it.

From the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) for the UPDATE_DISCONNECTED option (boldface added by me):

> When enabled, this option causes the update step to be skipped. It does not, however, prevent the download step. **The update step can still be added as a step target (see ExternalProject_Add_StepTargets()) and called manually.** This is useful if you want to allow developers to build the project when disconnected from the network (the network may still be needed for the download step though).

When you call `ExternalProject_Add` with a STEP_TARGETS option, however, `ExternalProject_Add_StepTargets` is called for you automatically.

One final thing: You don't need to call `find_package(Git REQUIRED)`, as you did in the first answer. By virtue of setting `GIT_REPOSITORY` in your call to `ExternalProject_Add`, the module itself will attempt to find git (and will issue a FATAL_ERROR message if it can't).

Comment: how can the target be build? the target created by STEP_TARGETS

Comment: @quetzalfir The target would be called "Catch-update", as pointed out in my answer. If you use make as your build tool, "make Catch-update"; if you use ninja, "ninja Catch-update".